# Exchange 2007 and 2010 Journal Messages Stuck In Queue

Tags: smtp, exchange-2007, exchange-2010, journalling

I have a simple setup of 2 e-mail servers.  My Exchange 2010 server, MS2010, is setup to forward all e-mails that it receives to the journaling mailbox.  The journal mailbox is located on my Exchange 2007 server, MS2007.  I have 2 messages in the last few days (since I've been watching) that simply fail to be received by the Journal mailbox on MS2007.  Here is the receive connector log of the failed transmission -

```
2011-10-04T19:45:04.567Z,MS2007\From MS2010,08CE226DD039B679,46,192.168.1.11:25,192.168.1.38:20523,>,250 2.1.0 Sender OK,
2011-10-04T19:45:04.567Z,MS2007\From MS2010,08CE226DD039B679,47,192.168.1.11:25,192.168.1.38:20523,<,RCPT TO:<Journal@mydomain.com> ORCPT=rfc822;Journal@mydomain.ws,
2011-10-04T19:45:04.567Z,MS2007\From MS2010,08CE226DD039B679,48,192.168.1.11:25,192.168.1.38:20523,>,250 2.1.5 Recipient OK,
2011-10-04T19:45:04.567Z,MS2007\From MS2010,08CE226DD039B679,49,192.168.1.11:25,192.168.1.38:20523,<,BDAT 22080 LAST,
2011-10-04T19:45:04.676Z,MS2007\From MS2010,08CE226DD039B679,50,192.168.1.11:25,192.168.1.38:20523,>,550 5.7.1 Requested action not taken: message refused,
2011-10-04T19:45:04.676Z,MS2007\From MS2010,08CE226DD039B679,51,192.168.1.11:25,192.168.1.38:20523,-,,Local
```

For comparison, I clipped out the transmission conversation of a successful journal message delivery -

```
2011-10-04T19:45:51.707Z,MS2007\From MS2010,08CE226DD039B67C,53,192.168.1.11:25,192.168.1.38:20532,>,250 2.1.0 Sender OK,
2011-10-04T19:45:51.707Z,MS2007\From MS2010,08CE226DD039B67C,54,192.168.1.11:25,192.168.1.38:20532,<,RCPT TO:<Journal@mydomain.com> ORCPT=rfc822;Journal@mydomain.ws,
2011-10-04T19:45:51.707Z,MS2007\From MS2010,08CE226DD039B67C,55,192.168.1.11:25,192.168.1.38:20532,>,250 2.1.5 Recipient OK,
2011-10-04T19:45:51.707Z,MS2007\From MS2010,08CE226DD039B67C,56,192.168.1.11:25,192.168.1.38:20532,<,BDAT 60301 LAST,
2011-10-04T19:45:52.160Z,MS2007\From MS2010,08CE226DD039B67C,57,192.168.1.11:25,192.168.1.38:20532,>,250 2.6.0 <2fc21244-4795-46f3-ba84-7e33eb2d3e04@journal.report.generator> Queued mail for delivery,
2011-10-04T19:45:52.176Z,MS2007\From MS2010,08CE226DD039B67C,58,192.168.1.11:25,192.168.1.38:20532,<,QUIT,
2011-10-04T19:45:52.176Z,MS2007\From MS2010,08CE226DD039B67C,59,192.168.1.11:25,192.168.1.38:20532,>,221 2.0.0 Service closing transmission channel,
2011-10-04T19:45:52.176Z,MS2007\From MS2010,08CE226DD039B67C,60,192.168.1.11:25,192.168.1.38:20532,-,,Local
```

What could be causing the `550 5.7.1 Requested action not taken: message refused,` in this case?  Where do I look?